# How do get a Cookie setted using BasicClientCookie in the executed application

Tags: java, httpclient

Here is a function to call an intern application where we want to authenticate with a cookie :

```
private InputStream recupererContenuHttp(String url, String certificat)     throws Exception {

BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(GestionSecurite.getInstance().getNomCookieCertificat(), certificat);

cookie.setPath("/");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response =  client.execute(get);

if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  throw new ModeleException("Erreur dans l'exécution de la génération de l'extraction : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
return response.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

I would like to recuperate the cookie in the called application to determine if I am authenticated with this:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

The line returns nothing.

What should I do ?

Thanks,

Pierrick

Answer (score 0):

I was with httpclient 4.2.7. With 4.5.2, it is now working,.

Thanks,

Pierrick